# How to check a string starts with a specified string in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to check a string is starting with a particular string or not, how can check that in kotlin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   val s = "hello"
   println(s.startsWith("hel")) // true
   println(s.startsWith("hal")) // false
```

Comment: Mark I have a doubt ,
I have a string eg.
var st="an error occurred 404 page not found"
Is there any way to find 404 is  exist or not in st

Comment: s.contains("404") will do the job, however you better test response status (should be 404, no need to check strings.